# Is it possible to install vim for a user?

Tags: linux, vim

I have a SSH Login to a dev computer (used for hosting PHP and Python files). It has vim installed, but a stripped down version of it - it has `syntax` and whole lot of other stuff disabled .

So, my question is - can I install my own "local" vim without a superuser account?

Comment: What kind of OS (or distro) is this? Are you sure it's disabled? What does ":version" say?

Comment: I'm on CentOS5.5 (according to `/etc/issue`), or Red Hat 4.1.2-4.6 (according to `/proc/version`). Yeah, I'm sure it's disabled - I used `:version` to check it

Comment: So you're sure the sysadmin can't take 2 seconds to type `yum install vim-enhanced` ?

Comment: @Keith, my thoughts exactly. I'm on Ubuntu myself and use package manager exclusively. But our sysadmin apparently doesn't trust repositories, or prefers building from source - because even asking him to reconfigure PHP meets strong resistance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. [Download Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php)
2. Change the prefix:

   2. When compiling, use the option `--prefix=/home/myaccount` (or whatever you want), or
   3. Edit the `prefix` option in `src/makefile` to something like `/home/myaccount` or just `$(HOME)` (thanks Heptite!)
3. When you run `make install`, it will install the files using the prefix you specified (e.g. binaries will be installed to `/home/myaccount/bin`)
4. Change your `prefix` to include `/home/myaccount/bin` in `.bash_profile` or `.profile`.
5. Success!!

Comment: While most sources prefer you to run configure by hand, the preferred way to do this kind of thing for Vim is to edit the src/Makefile and change the "prefix" variable to something like $(HOME)

Comment: @Heptite Thanks! I added your comment into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @thepurplepixel, I tried your solution and it almost worked, but ./configure complains about missing terminal library. I installed ncurses5 using `--prefix` and tried running vim's `configure` again, but it still complains. I tried `--with-tlib` option and without

Comment: @German I don't know *that* much about it... maybe somebody else can help.

Comment: @German Rumm: You need to tell Vim's `configure` where to find your ncurses installation. Execute `export CPPFLAGS="-I/ncursesprefix/include"` and `export LDFLAGS="-L/ncursesprefix/lib"`, where `/ncursesprefix` is the prefix you used to build ncurses. You may need to add the option `--with-tlib=ncurses` to Vim's `configure` options. Doing so anyway won't hurt. Then running `./configure ...` and `make` should build Vim with your ncurses library. @Heptite: How is modifying src/Makefile the "preferred" method of changing the prefix? I've always used `./configure --prefix=...`.

Comment: @garyjohn the CPPFLAGS/LDFLAGS piece really helped me. You should consider making is a separate answer or edit this one. It's too easy to miss in a comment. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `#prefix = $(HOME)` has been added to the Makefile by default now, so you (supposedly) only need to uncomment it for this to work.

Comment: I found this answer just added to my confusion since I don't know how to do option 1. "When compiling" - what does this mean? It would be more helpful if you gave the actual commands that should be run.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe copying a binary to the server and chmoding it to executable?

Perhaps you should contect your sysadmin or host to see if they can enable these features for you.

Comment: Nope, tried that, complains about missing libraries/shared objects. Can't ask sysadmin - he's lazy and kinda stupid (installing svn for 2 months already)